# Как установить значение переменной окружения на macOS, чтобы иметь к ней доступ из кода python

Tags: python, macos, unix

Я работаю с некоторым API, у меня есть ключ к нему, который я хотела бы хранить в переменной окружения (enviroment vars) и получать доступ из кода python с помощью os.environ из модуля os. Работаю на macOS Mojave в IDE PyCharm.

Как я могла бы установить значение переменной окружения в своей системе, чтобы затем иметь к ней доступ из кода в python?

```py
import os
print(os.environ['API_KEY'])
```

Comment: Может, `export myVar=$var` в Bash, а потом `if "myVar" in os.environ:` (и берёте `os.getenv('myVar')`) в Python?

Comment: если вы запускаете ваш скрипт из эмулятора терминала, где запущена какая-нибудь оболочка, то в стартовых скриптах этой оболочки и укажите переменную. а если вы запускаете эдакий «gui application», то там [всё сложнее](https://superuser.com/q/476752/454489), вплоть до того, что это ваше секретное значение станет доступно любому другому пользователю вашего компьютера.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я пишу обычного телеграмм бота, скрипт запускала из самой IDE, у меня это PyCharm. Сейчас попробовала запустить через терминал, предварительно прописав команду `export myVar=$var`, которую посоветовал @WiktorStribiżew, все работает, как нужно. Но что мне делать при запуске скрипта из самой IDE?

Comment: читайте вторую часть моего предыдущего комментария, после слов «а если вы запускаете эдакий». запускаете вы в вашем случае то, что назвали «ide». вот для этого «gui application» вам и надо указывать переменную. впрочем, эти самые «ide» обычно имеют возможность дополнить вызов запускаемых ими самими программ нужными переменными окружения. смотрите документацию к вашему «ide».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### При запуске скрипта через консоль:

Перед запуском скрипта прописать в Bash `export myVar=$var`.

#### При запуске скрипта из IDE:

Следует установить переменные окружения в самой IDE. Для PyCharm этот процесс подробно описан [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm).